# Google Play subscription inconsistent auto-renewal

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-developer-api

My app is using the /androidpublisher/v1 of googleapis to validate Google Play subscriptions.
(Will be upgraded to v2 in the near future)

Every month every user subscription is usually automatically renewed, and I get a new receipt response from the API of the following type:

```
{
 "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
 "initiationTimestampMsec": "<start timestamp>",
 "validUntilTimestampMsec": "<expiration timestamp>",
 "autoRenewing": ***true***
}
```

However, ever since 19/05/15 - the following scenarios started occurring -
At the end of every subscription, we're getting the following response:

```
{
 "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
 "initiationTimestampMsec": "<start timestamp>",
 "validUntilTimestampMsec": "<expiration timestamp>",
 "autoRenewing": ***false***
}
```

Which basically means that the subscription had not been renewed and is therefore cancelled.
However, after an attempt to ***resend*** the latest receipt to Google again, we are once again receiving a valid receipt, with new expiration:

```
{
 "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
 "initiationTimestampMsec": "<start timestamp>",
 "validUntilTimestampMsec": "<***new*** expiration timestamp>",
 "autoRenewing": ***true***
}
```

Is this a new issue with the old google API?
Has anyone else experienced such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google developers support, they have indeed found a bug which had caused issues around the dates mentioned above.

This has been fixed around beginning of June.